# You slept with your mouth open VS with your mouth opened (could be difference?)

Tags: participle-phrases

> You slept with your mouth open

> You slept with your mouth opened

Could be difference?

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141547/opened-vs-open/

Comment: Hardly anyone ever [*slept with one eye **opened**.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slept+with+one+eye+open%2Cslept+with+one+eye+opened&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslept%20with%20one%20eye%20open%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslept%20with%20one%20eye%20opened%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 3):

"Open" is the classic example of an "ergative" verb.

It can be used with an object

> The dentist opens John's mouth.

Or intransitively

> John's mouth opens.

Notice the object of the transitive verb is the subject of the intransitive verb.  This is why it is "ergative". The intransitive form means "nobody makes his mouth open, it happens by itself.

Now we can also form a passive form:

> John's mouth is opened (by the dentist)

The passive form also has "John's mouth" as the subject, but implies that there is "someone who makes his mouth open", even if the "by" phrase is omitted.

So think and understand the difference between "John's mouth opens" and "John's mouth is opened"

Now in the phrase "with your mouth open" relates to the intransitive form. And "with your mouth opened" relates to the passive form.  The first means that your mouth naturally opened when you slept.  The second means that someone pushed your mouth open as you slept!.

While both are grammatically correct, 99% of the time you mean

> You slept with your mouth open.

Comment: Thx u. But, I think the 'open' in the example is an adjective.

Comment: It is, but to understand the difference between the adjectives "with your mouth open" and participle-form "with your mouth opened", you need to understand the related verb.